# Get columns values by a primary key, sqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask

I was working on this project using `flask,` and I am trying to create a route where you can see a post's info (every post's an ID insert in a table like a primary key)

I was trying to display the row values by the primary key (id) on an HTML file. I mean something like this:

***primary key(id)-> title's value -> description's value***

And display them all together by just having the id (that we got by the route variable) that is the primary key.
However, I don't know if this is possible. Does someone have any idea?

[this is my .db file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGlth.png)

```
@app.route("/post/<id>")
def post_list(id):

    db = get_db()

    post_id = db.execute("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = ?", [id])
    result_id = post_id.fetchone()

    return "<h1>ID: {}</h1>".format(result_id["id"])
```

Comment: resolved: `.format(result_id["id"], result_id["title"], result_id["description"]` for anyone wondering :)